# mysql left join select top value from one table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have the next query:

```
SELECT chat.*, message.time as last_message, message.content as last_message_content 
FROM chat 
LEFT JOIN message ON chat.id = message.chat_id 
GROUP BY chat.id 
ORDER BY message.time ASC
```

now, I want to pick the newest message.time, but right now it gives me the first one..

any idea on how this could be accomplished?

thanks

Comment: `MAX(message.time)` ?

Comment: Can you post a small sample of each table, along with a sample of your desired query output from those tables?  You have run afoul of a common misuse of `GROUP BY` in MySQL -- if we see a sample of how you want the results to look, we can set you on the right path. In particular, we need to know if you want the most recent message.time per group or most recent for the entire table.

Comment: Is it possible to have a 'chat' with no 'messages'?

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get the last message time for the chat and join that back to the `message` table:

```
SELECT c.*, m.time as last_message, m.content as last_message_content 
FROM chat c LEFT JOIN
     (select chat_id, max(time) as last_message_time
      from message
      group by chat_id
     ) ml
     ON c.id = ml.chat_id LEFT JOIN
     message m
     ON m.chat_id = ml.chat_id and m.time = ml.lst_message_time
ORDER BY m.time ASC;
```

Do not use `group by` the way you were using it.  The columns from `message` come from *indeterminate* rows, so you have no control over which values are chosen.

Answer (score -1):

Sort it in DESC order to get the newest message.